# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Modal not working under Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am using `Laravel` 4 with Twitter Bootstrap 3 for my application. When I try to use the modal, it is not working well. It only fades-in, shows blank page and nothing more. I know I have the proper hierarchy of `jquery` and `bootstrap.js` files because other `javascript` functions of bootstrap like `popover` and `carousel` are working well. Only the modal is not working.

I am using this bootstrap boilerplate of modal for testing:

```
<!-- Small modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the hierarchy of my `js` files:

```
{{ HTML::script('_/js/jquery.js')}}
{{ HTML::script('_/js/bootstrap.js') }}
```

I can't figure out what and where is the glitch. Hope someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: Does it realy have something to do with Laravel? Any DevTools console output?

Comment: try adding `type="button"`?